# PDO error message: Call to a member function errorInfo() on a non-object in

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I get always this message."Call to a member function errorInfo() on a non-object in"
I connect to the database with PDO and it work localhost server, but i need connect to another server. Here is my code:

```
class Database{

protected $db_name = "develop_for_me";
protected $host = "phpmyadmin.develop.forme";
protected $name = "develop_benj";
protected $password = "myname2015";
protected $conn;

function __construct()
{
    try {
        $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host.";dbname=".$this->db_name , $this->name, $this->password);

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $e->getMessage();
        print_r($this->conn->errorInfo());

    }
}
```

thank you for help!

Comment: `$this->conn` is null because an exception happens.

Comment: `$e->getMessage();` this doesn't do anything. did you mean to print or log the message? I'm guessing your login credentials don't work on the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this message because your error handling is wrong.

1. Make your constructor the *proper* way

   ```
   function __construct()
   {
       $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host.";dbname=".$this->db_name , $this->name, $this->password);
   }
   ```
2. Read the error message and fix the error

Comment: Why do you remove the try?

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    //Here you have an error : so $this->conn is not set.
    $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host.";dbname=".$this->db_name , $this->name, $this->password);

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    //$this->conn is NULL so its not an object.
    $e->getMessage();
    print_r($this->conn->errorInfo());

}
```

Answer (score -1):

When an exception happens it's will jump to catch block and the assigment will not happens. Do not forget the print/echo the message

```
function __construct() {
    try {
        $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host.";dbname=".$this->db_name , $this->name, $this->password);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
       echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: The try is the problem or has more?

Answer (score -2):

So I rewrote the code:

```
try {
        $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host.";dbname=".$this->db_name , $this->name, $this->password);



    } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die("Could not connect to database");

    }
```

Now is working fine.